# Remote Service - restarts after closing the launching Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm blocked with this for a few days and can't find the answer on this.

I start a remote service from an Activity. After starting the service, I close the launching Activity.(I press a button in the Activity to launch the remote service).

The thing that happens is that my service gets restarted! when I close the launching Activity.
I put the launching Activity in background,thus enters onPause() state and then I close it from task manager.

When I do that, my Remote Service gets restarted and is on again in about 2 seconds. 
All the internal variables are going to be reset and I don't want that.

-I don't want to use useForeground() method because I don't want my service to be visible in Notification

-also I want to use onBind() with the service

I've declared it in this way:

I currently start a Remote Service like this and the service starts(I can see it in the services region):

```
//button clicked form onCreate() launching Activity
    btnStartSrv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {                       
        startService(new Intent("RM_SRV_AIDL"));//the name of the service
     }
    });
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml I've declared the Remote Service like this:

```
  <service
        android:name="com.mainActivity.MyRemoteService"
        android:label="somenameService"
        android:process=":remote"
    >    
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RM_SRV_AIDL" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </service>
```

How do I pass the restarting issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you really want because you say you want `onBind()` but there is none of it in your code snippet moreover you use `startService()` which is usually the other way you start `Services`.

However these may help you:

["A service can be both started and have connections bound to it."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) So you don't have to choose between a bounded `Service` (`onBind()`) or an explicitly started/stopped one (`startService()`).

Also don't forget about setting the `Service FLAGS` upon starting with  [`onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29), like [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

Hope these helped.

Comment: I use only startService(). for onBind() way,  I'll use it later after starting with startService() and fixing the reseting problem. Now reseting the service is the main issue

Comment: ok, have you tried setting the flags I wrote about?
nevermind, just saw it in the other post

Comment: Are you sure you are not closing the service as well when using your task manager? That should explain the restart issue. Try to not use any task manager, just let the system stop your activity after not using it and check if your service closes too that way.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that my service is restarted when I close the launching activity. 
I press the home button or back button and the activity goes in backgroud. Actually it passes in onPause() state. Then it remains like this until you close it from the task manager. From other part. I don't know how to close it but for sure I'm not closing the service. The only place where I can kill the service is from app/Running
1 thing I've noticed during service is resetting(after activity closes): says 0 procceses 1 service and after restarting 1process 1 service.
for sure I'm not doing something ok here

Comment: I still don't see clearly what and where are you killing but if you kill the process it's not surprising that the service is being killed and restarted too because they are in the same process by default. That's why I'm saying that let it run and see if service ever gets restarted or not.
I mean maybe it's working already and problem is that you killing it in a way Android would (almost) never would.